# jquery filter an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to filter an array once the user enter in a city. I was able to populate the drop down menu.  However there is an issue with the search bar. It is going to to filter out the array list to whatever the user typed in. I cant seem to get the if statement to work

HTML :

```
    <html>
      // the html code  
       <body>

     <div class="jumbotron">


      <br>
      <button id="trigger-btn" class="btn">

      </button>
      <div id="container" class="hide">
          <input type="text" id="search" class="form-control"/>
          <br>
      </div>
  </div>
      <span class="cities" id="cities"></span>
     </body>

       </html>
```

Javascript :

```
    // the array
    var Cities_Colorado =  ["ACRES GREEN", "AGUILAR", "AIR FORCE ACADEMY", "AKRON", "ALAMOSA", "ALAMOSA EAST", "ALLENSPARK", "ALMA", "ANTONITO", "APPLEWOOD", "ARBOLES",
        "ARISTOCRAT RANCHETTES", "ARRIBA", "ARVADA", "ASPEN", "ASPEN PARK", "ATWOOD", "AULT", "AURORA", "AVON", "AVONDALE", "BASALT", "BATTLEMENT MESA", "BAYFIELD",
        "BENNETT", "BERKLEY", "BERTHOUD", "BETHUNE", "BEULAH VALLEY", "BLACK FOREST", "BLACK HAWK", "BLANCA", "BLUE RIVER", "BONANZA", "BOONE", "BOULDER", "BOW MAR",
        "BRANSON", "BRECKENRIDGE", "BRIGHTON", "BROOKSIDE", "BROOMFIELD", "BRUSH", "BUENA VISTA", "BURLINGTON", "BYERS", "CALHAN", "CAMPION", "CAMPO", "CANON CITY",
        "CARBONDALE"]

     // the filter list

      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#trigger-btn').click(function(){
            $('#container').toggleClass('hide')
             })
            $.each(Cities_Colorado, function(key,value){
              (" "+key+ ": "+ value);
               $("#container").append("<span>" +"<li>"+value+ "</li>"+"</span>");

               $("#search").each(function(){

                $(value).text().indexOf();
               // array filter 
               $(value).keyup(function(){
                var test=$(key).val()
                if ( indexOf( value ) === -1 ) {

                }else{ 
                }   
               })
              })
               })
              })
```

Comment: And 2 spelling errors in the title. That much hurrying doesn't inspire people to help.

Comment: you should use jquery-ui autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to filter a list based on user input, you could repopulate the list on each keyup, testing each city with a regular expression.

```
$('.search').on('keyup', function() {
  let html = '', search = this.value;
  $.each(Cities_Colorado, function(index, city) {
    html += (new RegExp('^' + search, 'i')).test(city) ? `<li>${city}</li>` : '';
  });
  $('.cities').html(html);
}).trigger('keyup'); //initialize
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jbuvcyzx/1/

I'm not sure the code you provided actually does anything, so I didn't copy it verbatim. This is just an example.

Other thoughts:

`$.each()` works differently depending what you're iterating over.

```
$.each(array, function(index, value) {});
$.each(object, function(key, value) {});
```

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

`<li>` belong inside a `<ol>` or `<ul>`

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp

[Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) are great where supported.

[Regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

[Ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

As mentioned in a comment, [jQuery Autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) is also pretty slick if you're using [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/).